# Public vs Protected

Tags: c#, public, protected

I'm very confuse on why classes compose of `public` and `protected` methods/variables.
Why only extended classes can access `protected` methods/variables? Can someone else can help me enlighten the difference between `public` and `protected` and it's functionality.

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: You haven't specified what language you're talking about - and the "why" is fundamentally likely to be answer by "because that's what the specification says"... you should clarify your question.

Comment: The programming language does not matter. A public property will be available outside the class. A protected property will not be available outside the class but will be available in child classes. Likewise with methods, and this is a way in which OOP programming works. Read more on OOP on google.

Comment: @Slavic: The general principle may be similar, but there may well be specific semantic differences between different languages.

Comment: General principle is what was required, Oli, and it's not general principle, it's general OOP concepts.

Comment: the programming language is C#.. @Slavic, why only the child classes can access protected property? what is the main purpose of it? why it could not be accessed by the class who instantiated on it?

Comment: It makes for more robust coding, if you want the short answer. The long answer, please read OOP material on google.

Comment: I've added the `C#` tag now to avoid further confusion

Comment: or it simply when to use the protected properties and public properties?

Comment: "there may well be specific semantic differences between different languages" -- there aren't. And even if there were, they wouldn't be relevant to answering this question.

Comment: "or it simply when to use the protected properties and public properties?" -- I suggest never using `protected`; it's a misbegotten feature. If you use `public` whenever you need access outside the class and never use `public`, your code will be fine.

Comment: "why only the child classes can access protected property?" -- Because that's what `protected` *means*. If that's not what you want (and why would you) then don't use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can only derived classes can access protected members?

Because that's the *definition* of "protected". The accessibility domain of a protected member is the class and its derived classes.

Perhaps you intended to ask:

> Why can I **not** always access a protected member even when I am in a derived class?

It's complicated. For a detailed explanation, see my six part series "Why can I not access a protected member from a derived class?"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/protected/

Comment: bad link ......

Answer (score 4):

Well, why they do is because that's simply what they are for. I think perhaps you are wondering why one might want to. The simple answer is because derived classes need to access them, and outside classes don't.

Access modifiers (as well as `public` and `protected`, there are `private`, `internal` and `protected internal`) are a means to keep code as understandable as possible to reduce errors.

There are languages without any form of encapsulation. At their most extreme, any code can change any piece of any data. A disciplined coder will reduce the number of places a given type of data is manipulated, but it may still not be obvious all the combinations of operations that could leave objects* in different states. The situation gets worse when their code is then used as part of someone else's code.

Access modifiers help us to deal with this. We default to having members private. Then the only places the member can be accessed is inside the class itself. This means:

1. The only places a mistake in how they are manipulated can be, is inside the class.
2. The only code that has to worry about keeping those members in a consistent state, is inside the class, and that code doesn't have to worry about the possibility of other code upsetting that.
3. You can get a complete picture of every way that those fields are manipulated, by looking at one class's definition, which is normally in one file and rarely in more than two.

This makes it much easier for us to code well.

Of course, a class where everything is private isn't very useful. We generally have to let some members be public. Typically we have our fields private, some helpful methods private, and then some public methods and properties use those. We can still examine all possible manipulations on the private members by examining just that one class, though we've opened up calling the members that do so to other classes. As such, these members give us an interface between the code inside and outside the class, the boundary across which we protect the state of the class from error while providing useful functionality to other code.

It should be clear by now that we don't make something public, unless we need to, but we do need to for useful work to be possible.

Making a member protected gives us a middle ground. We're still reducing the places something can be manipulated, but not so heavily. Typically, this is done so that a derived class can provide its own mechanism to a general interface defined in the base.

There are fewer cases where it's used, because normally we either can keep things private - which is safer - or have to be public to be useful. One of the most common cases, are where the public members provide functionality and the protected define means to implement it. For example `HttpEncoder` provides several methods for dealing with the issue of encoding strings for HTML, but there are two protected abstract methods that derived classes override to provide the functionality common to the several different methods. Outside classes don't need to access those, but derived classes do.

A practical example. Say we have a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanging`. This interface means that it must keep track of `PropertyChangingEventHandler` handlers, and raise events when a property is about to change.

We don't want outside classes to raise that event, because that's not their business and having them do so is just going to result in errors.

We must let derived classes do so, because they may define their own properties the base class doesn't know about.

Therefore we define a protected method in this base class that raises the event. Outside classes cannot call it (reduced risk of it being called incorrectly), but derived classes can (ability to do the job they need to do).

*People from an object-oriented background might not even consider such pieces of data to be "objects".

Comment: The meaning of the term "outside classes" is unclear here. Derived classes are often outside of the class/file/package/module/assembly in which protected member is defined.

Also, there are good arguments that, since protected and public both escape encapsulation and expose the API, there's no need for the former and it just causes problems. (People have been known to write a derived class with a public method that calls the protected method that they need.) See, e.g., https://in.relation.to/2011/04/28/introduction-to-ceylon-part-2/ (search for "protected")

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is in the context of Java like language.

- `public` - can be accessed from any class
- `protected` - can be accessed from a sub / derived class only